# Store and Load windows session from command line

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

How can I store the current state of open programs in Hard disk  and then after several restarts restore that particular session? (all through cmd).

It's like hibernate in window, the difference  being the session can be saved saved and restored when desired.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. Hibernate only stores until a restart occurs and the old information (opened apps) is discarded. Sleep as well flushes memory once restarted. out of curiosity why do you need to store open apps and restart several times? why not just save your work and restart as many times as you want?

Comment: I want to do this several time in a day and the number of running apps more than 10 in each time, so it's difficult to this in each time. yes the hibernate can't do this, but I think it's may be possible by assembly code in cmd as like as hibernate code.

Comment: I'm just not understanding why you want to restart so much with programs running. Why can't you just save your work and set your programs to start with windows?

Comment: @emily What you're asking makes no sense. It's not really possible. You're asking for a feature that doesn't exist.